# How to save files to a directory and append those files to a list in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

**Scenario:**

I want to check whether if a directory contains a certain '.png' image file. If so, this image file along with all the other files (with png extension only) gets stored in a different directory. (The solution I am looking for should work in all OS platforms i.e Windows, Unix, etc.) and in a remote server i.e (FTP etc.)

I have tried the following code below:

```
import os, sys
import shutil
import pathlib
import glob

def search():
    image_file = 'picture.png'
    try:
        arr = []  #List will be used to append all the files in a particular directory.
        directory = pathlib.Path("collection") #checks if the collection directory exists.

        files = []
        #need to convert the PosixPath (directory) to a string.
        [files.extend(glob.glob(str(directory) + "/**/*.png", recursive = True))]

        res = [img for img in files if(img in image_file)]  #checks if the image is within the list of files i.e 'picture.png' == 'collection\\picture.png'

        if str(bool(res)):  #If True...proceed
            print("Image is available in image upload storage directory")

            for file in files:
                transfer_file = str(file)
                shutil.copy(file, 'PNG_files/')   #send all the files to a different directory i.e 'PNG_files' by using the shutil module.
                arr.append(transfer_file)
            return arr
        else:
            print("image not found in directory")
    except OSError as e:
        return e.errno

result = search() #result should return the 'arr' list. This list should contain png images only.
```

**However, during execution, the For loop is not getting executed. Which means:**

1. The image files are not stored in the 'PNG_files' directory.
2. The images are not getting appended in the 'arr' list.

The code above the For loop worked as expected. Can anyone explain to me what went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues:

In this line

```py
res = [img for img in files if(img in image_file)]  #checks if the image is within the list of files i.e 'picture.png' == 'collection\\picture.png'
```

you should check the other way around (as written in the comment): `image_file in img`, e.g. `picture.png in collection/picture.png`.

`str(directory) + "/**/*.png"` is not OS independent. If you need this to work on Windows, too, you should use `os.path.join(str(directory), '**', '*.png')` instead!

This check is incorrect: `if str(bool(res)):`. It's actually always true, because `bool(res)` is either True or False, `str(bool(res))` is either `"True"` or `"False"`, but both are actually True, as neither is an empty string. Correctly: `if res:`.

And finally, you're missing the creation of the `PNG_files` directory. You need to either manually create it before running the script, or call [os.mkdir()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkdir).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Just one question, will os.mkdir() work for a client as well? Can it work on a local server? And for the rest, I will try it out and let you know!

Comment: If `os.mkdir()` doesn't work (for example because of permission issues), then your `shutil.copy()` won't, either.

Comment: os.mkdir() works but shutil.copy doesn't work. Also, I have made the following changes as mentioned in your code, but it still doesn't work. :(

Comment: You should remove your giant try block to see the actual error. you're getting.

Comment: I am getting this error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'picture.png'. I don't understand why. The image is seen in the directory (collection) but why does it throw an error?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows.

Comment: That's probably the issue. My guess is that `"/**/*.png"` won't work in Windows, since Windows is using \s. Let me update my answer.

Comment: Yes, I got the solution. The initial image should contain its absolute path. Otherwise, the system won't be able to recognize it.